# Is there a way to map a set to a string without creating many set instances?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator, set, key-value

I have a school project that involves recommending a university course to students to study based on four favorite subjects each user enters.

My approach is to use `HashMap` in Java: `HashMap<String, Set<String>>`. The course is the simple string, while each set contains the four subjects required for the course.

Each entry should be added manually but in turn it requires many instances of the Set objects for each entry:

```
Set<String> setA = new HashSet<String>(); // for first pair

Set<String> setB = new HashSet<String>(); // for second pair.
```

And so on...

For each key/value entry, I want to check/compare the value (set of subjects) with the four subjects entered by the user and if the set contains the entered subjects, the key (course) is added to a matches array.

Does anyone have any idea on how I should go about this?

I have tried working on this. I really need to meet the deadline

Comment: Also, why are you choosing a Set as the values? Do you want each subject to be unique? If not, you can just use a regular ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

What I'm assuming you want is a Map.Entry. You mentioned in your question you want to use a HashMap. To loop through a HashMap's list of values you would do something like this:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> eachEntry : hashMap.entrySet()) 
{
    int key = eachEntry.getKey(); 
    int value = eachEntry.getValue(); 
}
```

In my example it's a hashmap containing Integer key value pairs, but you can change it to the type you want. A quick google search would show how to go through a Set inside of a hashmap. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can compare values this way , by iterating through the hashMap keys

```
    for(String course: hashMap.keySet()) {
     //Convert all the set values to lower case. Also do the same for user entered subjects set.
     Set<String> newSet = hashMap.get(course).stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
                     if( newSet.containsAll(userEnteredCourses)) {
                         matchesArray.add(course);
                     }
                 }
```